# ListView does not update in activity onCreate method or buttom onClickListener method

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have a listView that is created in onCreate method.As below, and read data from a Stored Procedure.
I Used CallabeStatement.

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.type_of_dairy);

    try
    {

        CallableStatement catCallable;
        ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
        catCallable = connectionHelper.getConnection().prepareCall("{ CALL SpGetDairyCategory}");
        catCallable.execute();

        resultSet = catCallable.getResultSet();

        setResultSet(resultSet);

        if(getResultSet().next()) {
            do {

                String typeString = resultSet.getString("CategoryName");
                int typeId = resultSet.getInt("CategoryId");
                integerArraList.add(typeId);
                typeArray.add(typeString);
                typeAdapter.getItemViewType(R.id.listView); // adapter for first ListView
                dairyType.setAdapter(typeAdapter);//dairyType is my first List View

            }while(resultSet.next());

        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something is  wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

In the above code, I got Id of Category Id and name,and passed them into two ArrayLists named integerArrayList and typeArray.

I generate the second ListView with the Id of category that i  got from the above Stored Procedure.
I do it in dairyType(first ListView)onClickListener.
here is the code

```
dairyType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                try {
                    flavorAapter.clear();
                    CallableStatement proCallable;
                    ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                    proCallable = connectionHelper.getConnection().prepareCall("{call SpGetCategoryProducts(?)}");
                    proCallable.setInt(1, integerArraList.get(dairyType.getCheckedItemPosition())); //integerArrayList contains the categoryId from the first Store Procedure
                    resultSet2 = proCallable.executeQuery();
//The second Stored Procedure get the Id and return some value as you see
                    if (resultSet2.next()) {
                        do {
                            int flavourId;
                            int weitgh;
                            int price;
                            weitgh = resultSet2.getInt("Weight");
                            price = resultSet2.getInt("Price");
                            String flavourString = resultSet2.getString("Name");
                            flavourId = resultSet2.getInt("Id");


                            dairyArray.add(flavourString);

                            idOfCategories.add(flavourId);
                            weightArray.add(weitgh);
                            priceArray.add(price);

                            flavorAapter.getItemViewType(R.id.listView2);
                            dairyFlavour.destroyDrawingCache();
                            dairyFlavour.setAdapter(flavorAapter);

                        } while (resultSet2.next());
                        connectionHelper.closeConnection();
                    } else {
                        flavorAapter.clear();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dairyArray.clear();
                }
            }
        });
```

Ok, so i generate the second Listview sucessfully as i wanted,
the problem is in the insert Buttom,
Now i have ArrayList of Name, Weight, Price and Id.( I use Id as an argument that passes to last Stored Procedure.
So I have to call another Stored Procedure to insert all these data into DB(Name,Weight,Price)
But it doesnt insert the changed items values.
It means, i select an item from the first ListView,The second Listview generate and i choose one of them, but when i change my select in the first ListView, it still insert the id of first ListView.
here is my insert code via buttom named apply.

```
    apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                    dairyFlavour.invalidateViews();
                    dairyType.invalidateViews();
                    typeAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    flavorAapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    int weight = weightArray.get(dairyFlavour.getCheckedItemPosition()); //weitgh from previous SP
                    int price = priceArray.get(dairyFlavour.getCheckedItemPosition()); //price from previous SP
                    String count = "";
                    int c;
                    count = countOfProduct.getText().toString(); // insert the count of product via editText
                    c = Integer.parseInt(count); // cast the cound to Integer
                    we = idOfCategories.get(dairyFlavour.getCheckedItemPosition());//the id i got in previous SP

                    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
                    ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
                    callableStatement = connectionHelper.getConnection().prepareCall("{call SpInsertLoadCityProducts(?, ?, ? ,?)}");

                    callableStatement.setInt(1, we);
                    callableStatement.setInt(2, weight);
                    callableStatement.setInt(3, price);
                    callableStatement.setInt(4, c);
                    callableStatement.executeQuery();

                }catch(SQLException e){

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


            }
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FinishLoading.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

In view it is ok and as i change the first ListView the second ListView generated as desired.
But in insert, i only insert the first chose values into DB, and when i change the selection in the first ListView and choose another product in second ListView and click apply buttom, the first data is inserted.

Any Suggestion?
If you are confused ask question to make myself more clear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I should clear every ArrayList befor storing data.
when first time get index and data, i should clear ArrayList and again fill out them as below.

```
        dairyTypes.clear();
        integerArraList.clear();
        typeArray.clear();
```

and also

```
            flavorAapter.clear();
```